# respose.sendredirect issue of url

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am sending a url from bean class like this

```
 String url="/jsp/browse/browse.jsp";
    response.sendRedirect(url);
```

but in browser it want to call the url

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/faces/jsp/browse/browse.jsp
```

but it is calling

```
http://localhost:8080/jsp/browse/browse.jsp
```

please tell what may the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U could write as below:

```
String url="../jsp/browse/browse.jsp";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe writing

```
String url="jsp/browse/browse.jsp";
```

could solve the problem, because with /jsp/browse/browse.jsp you're passing an absolute path

Answer (score 0):

Provide the full URL including protocol, host and port and you are save.

```
String url="http://localhost:8080/jsp/browse/browse.jsp";
```

Additionally you should replace the protocol/host/port part with some variable